# Pandas.read_csv “unexpected end of data” Error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a dataset using pd.read_csv() am getting an error.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_csv("/content/data.txt", sep=" ", header=0, names=['word', 'label1', 'label2'],engine="python")
```

and I am getting the error

```
Error: unexpected end of data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
```

My `Data.txt` file looks like

```
n en en
wish en en
very en en
happy en en
b en en
" univ univ
day en en
to en en
u en en
........... univ univ
```

When I replace this `"` with some other punctuation, it works fine.

What can I do to fix this? and why this is happening with this `"` marks?

Comment: A " in a csv allows for a column to include spaces, commas and new lines. Everything beyond that " will be treated as a single value.

Comment: you can specify a different quote character by setting `quotechar`

Comment: @GarrGodfreySo, what should I do now?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes. Its working fine now after use this ```quotechar``` . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set param **quoting as 3**.

> **quoting:** int or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default 0
>
> Control field quoting behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of
> QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE
> (3).

**Example:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("t.txt", sep=" ", header=0, names=['word', 'label1', 'label2'],engine="python", quoting=3)
```

**Output:**

```
          word label1 label2
0         wish     en     en
1         very     en     en
2        happy     en     en
3            b     en     en
4            "   univ   univ
5          day     en     en
6           to     en     en
7            u     en     en
8  ...........   univ   univ
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html